# "[Errno 13] Permission denied error" while running Py script in Ansible

Tags: ansible

When, I'm running a Python script via an Ansible playbook, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/Dest/To/Repo/HW.py", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 13] Permission denied", "rc": 13}
```

I did add the `sudo: yes` line:

Here is my yaml file:

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  sudo: yes
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: check out a git repository
    git: repo={{ repo_url }} dest=/Dest/To/Repo/ accept_hostkey=yes
    vars:
      repo_url: https://github.com/lorin/mezzanine-example.git

  - name: Running the Python Script
    command: /Dest/To/Repo/HW.py
```

The HW.py script is just `print("Hello World")`

**Is there anything which I need to do, regarding the permissions error?**

Comment: I can see one possible problem with your script: the `HW.py` file may not have execution rights. Try the following command: `command: /usr/bin/python /Dest/To/Repo/HW.py`

Comment: @SebastianStigler Worked. Pl write it down as an answer :) .  However, I get a warning, which says: `[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Instead of sudo/sudo_user, use become/become_user and make sure become_method is 'sudo' (default).
This feature will be removed in a future release.
Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.` .  How do I handle it, in a remote EC2?

Comment: Please stop using the tag "ansible-ad-hoc" for questions that have nothing to do with [Ad-Hoc Commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_adhoc.html)

Comment: @Dawny33 just replace the `sudo: yes` with `become: yes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use umask to add execution rights in you git module call :

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  sudo: yes
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: check out a git repository
    git: repo={{ repo_url }} dest=/Dest/To/Repo/ accept_hostkey=yes
    umask: 0022
    vars:
      repo_url: https://github.com/lorin/mezzanine-example.git
```

Comment: You need to decide if you use Ansible notation or pure YAML. If you decide for YAML, you need to apply proper indentation for the syntax to be valid. Finally, it's pretty easy to check that the repository in question does not contain `HW.py` file, so the solution likely would not work.